# React Native: How to response event in a overlay view and then pass through the event to next layer view

Tags: react-native

I have a bubble view. when someone tap outside of bubble, bubble will close, and then next layout will response event that listening.

[explain image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceYKo.png)

- I put the bubble on a modal view, when I tap **i am a bubble**, it will do something.
- When I tap outside of bubble, bubble will close. If there are some component listening some event, just trigger it, as like there is no modal. For example, When I tap **click me**, the modal will be destroyed, and then the button event will trigger

What can I do, to implement it. Thanks a lot.